# How to prevent sorting when there is a textfield inside a header?

Tags: jquery, datatables

One of my headers contains a `textfield` :

```
<table id="list" class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Immatriculation<div class="input-group"><input type="text" id="immatriculation" class="form-control" /></div></th>
         <th>Status connectivité</th>
         <th>Status mouvement</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>

list = $("#list").DataTable({...});
```

By default when we click on a `header` column then `DataTables` sorts the table through the clicked column. My problem is the `textfield` inside the `header` : when I click this `textfield` then `DataTable` sorts the data through that column. So how to prevent `DataTable` from sorting when I click the `textfield` `#immatriculation` inside of the `header` ?

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/4q12dsfz/ ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The sorting should trigger if I click the text accompaning the field. So add a text before the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('#immatriculation').click(function() {
return false;
});
```